# Mongoose mapreduce: map function using array.some

Tags: mapreduce, mongoose

This Javascript works fine outside of my map function:

```
var cribs = ["list","tree"];

if ( cribs.some(function(i){return (new RegExp(i,'gi')).test("a long list of words");}) ) {
 console.log('match');
}
```

(it just searches a string with the values from an array).

Although using it in my map function doesn't work:

```
var o = {};
o.map = function () { 
    if ( cribs.some(function(i){return (new RegExp(i,'gi')).test(this.name);}) ) {
        emit(this, 1) ;
    }
}
o.out = { replace: 'results' }
o.verbose = true;
textEntriesModel.mapReduce(o, function (err, model, stats) {
    model.find(function(err, data){
        console.log(data);
    });
})
```

It doesn't emit anything, so I have an empty result set. No errors.

If I don't use array.some, instead I just use a plain regex, then it works fine:

```
o.map = function () { 
    if(this.name.match(new RegExp(/list/gi))) {
        emit(this, 1) ;
    }
}
```

So my question is, why doesn't the above array.some function work within my map function?

I have a long list of words that I need to match, so I don't really want to write a regex for them individually, where the above *should* work.

Here is a jsfiddle of the function that I'm trying to use in my map function: http://jsfiddle.net/tnq7b/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make `cribs` available to the `map` function by adding it to the `scope` option:

```js
var cribs = ["list","tree"];
var o = {};
o.map = function () { 
    if (cribs.some(function(i){return (new RegExp(i,'gi')).test(this.name);})) {
        emit(this, 1);
    }
}
o.out = { replace: 'results' };
o.scope = { cribs: cribs };
o.verbose = true;
textEntriesModel.mapReduce(o, function (err, model, stats) {
    model.find(function(err, data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```